# OnClick event not working for linkbutton in a master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asplinkbutton

This is the html ,

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="hlnkLogoffF" runat="server" Text="Logoff" OnClick="hlnkLogoffF_Click" ></asp:LinkButton>
```

This is the code behind,

```
protected void hlnkLogoffF_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do something here
}
```

When i run this, i get the following error,

> "The resource cannot be found. "

Comment: I think your error has nothing to do with the `LinkButton`. Remove the `LinkButton` from the aspx and run your code again. Do you get the same error?

Comment: @JasonEvans I get a null exception after clicking the linkbutton. The application works fine when the linkbutton is removed.

Comment: OK, can you post the "OnClick" code of the LinkButton? The NULL exception is impossible to solve without seeing your code.

Comment: This link button is inside of the gridview or any asp.net controls ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
      // Your code here
}
```

in code behind of master page.

Also

What happens if you turn off validating with CausesValidation setting to false?

Answer (score 0):

i tried to run your code

.aspx

```
  <asp:LinkButton ID="hlnkLogoffF" runat="server" Text="Logoff"     OnClick="hlnkLogoffF_Click" ></asp:LinkButton>
```

.Cs

```
    protected void hlnkLogoffF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

i Haven't get any error.Could you please post the code inside the click event.?